# Linked list doesn't change in Golang

Tags: go, linked-list

My question is that when I made the **head** point to **head.next**

the **input.Val** still remains 1 instead of 2(which is the next value).

```
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}

func test(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    head = head.Next
    return head
}

func main() {

    var input, input2 ListNode
    input = ListNode{Val: 1, Next: &input2}}
    input2 = ListNode{Val: 2} 

    test(&input)
    fmt.Println(input.Val)
}
```

Comment: You have your next in `input2` and yet you try to use the next of `input` to access `input2`.

Comment: You only changed the value of a local variable / function argument in `test`.

Comment: @Ullaakut, sorry i correct my post, my question is why i input address to function, and change the linked list, but nothing changed.

Comment: @bereal, but i put the address to the function, not value, why it won't change.

Comment: @BlockMo the local variable `head` is a pointer or address, indeed. By assigning to this variable, you change the value of the pointer, making the variable pointing to something else. The underlying data does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is fixed:

https://play.golang.org/p/VUeqh71nEaN

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}

func test(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    head = head.Next
    return head
}

func main() {

    var input1, input2 ListNode
    input1 = ListNode{Val: 1, Next: &input2}
    input2 = ListNode{Val: 2, Next: &input1}

    input := test(&input1)
    fmt.Println(input.Val)
}
```

Outputs

`2`

The problems were that you don't use the return value of your `test` function, and you passed a node that doesn't have a `Next` value.